# Can we get the each api call response time in Soapui?

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have set of test cases ReusableComponent test Suite.

I can not run the ReusableComponent alone.It does not have session and otherstuff. When calling from other suite, it will be passed necessary data to reusable component.

Can we get the each api call response time using below closure?

```
    testSuite = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.testSuites["ReusableComponent"]
//Loop thru each case of the suite and find those matching properties and clear them
testSuite.testCaseList.each { testcase ->
            testcase.testStepList.each{testStepName ->
    log.info(testStepName.name)
    def props = testcase.testSteps["$testStepName"].testRequest.response.timeTaken
    def msg = props ?: 'None'
    log.info "Reponse Time for ${testStepName} test are : ${msg}"
 }
}
```

I am getting following error:

```
Can not get Property TestRequest on Null object.
```

This error message says that since I did not run this test case it says. But can not run the ReusableComponent alone. Is there any one to get the time after the entire run, need to get the time from ReusableComponent suite only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below statement would give you time taken for the request call.

```
log.info "Time taken : ${testRunner.timeTaken}"
```

If used in `TearDown Script` of test case, then it would give execution time for the test case.

If test suite `TearDown Script`, then use `log.info runner.timeTaken`

Comment: Eg., i have few groovy script and number increment etc.. Can we get the response time for each REST call ONLY using Tear down script?